# What happens to a function when I do a `bind(this)`?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a `Set` to maintain a bunch of functions where after calling it once, I can remove it from the set. This is my code below:

```
let onceWrapper = function() {
  let args = arguments;
  Set.delete(eventName, onceWrapper);
  func.apply(this, arguments);
}

Set.add(eventName, onceWrapper.bind(this));
```

I'm noticing that when I set a breakpoint **after** the `Set.add(eventName, onceWrapper.bind(this));` line, and run a `Set.has(onceWrapper)` or `Set.has(onceWrapper.bind(this))` in the console, it always returns false. Is there a way I could work around this? What is the explanation as to why my function changes? For what it's worth, when I console.log the function in the Set it returns `[native code]`. Thanks :)

Comment: [Spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-function.prototype.bind), [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: I would never expect `Set.has(onceWrapper.bind(this))` to return `true`. `.bind` returns a completely new function every time, so the Set cannot ever have contained that function.

Comment: what is Set.add(a,b) ?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai And `Set.delete(a, b)`, for that matter…

Answer (score 1):

> What happens to a function when I do a `bind(this)`?

Nothing, the original function (the one you call `bind` on) is completely unaffected by the call. But `bind` returns a **new** function (which is not the same as the function you called it on) that, when called, will call the original ensuring that `this` is set to `bind`'s first argument.

I should note that I have no idea what `Set` is in your code. It clearly isn't the standard [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), since that doesn't have **`static`** `add` and `has` methods. If it's an *instance* of the standard `Set`, then there are at least two reasons why `onceWrapper` isn't in it when you check: [`add`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-set.prototype.add) only accepts a **single** argument (which is odd in my view, but never mind). So **if** `Set` is an instance of `Set`, `Set.add(eventName, onceWrapper.bind(this))` will add only `eventName` to it. The other reason is as described above.

Using a **normal** `Set` called `things`, this should help make things more clear:

```js
function onceWrapper() {
    console.log(typeof this);
}

const things = new Set();

const boundOnceWrapper = onceWrapper.bind(this);
things.add(boundOnceWrapper);

// This logs false because each call to `bind` creates a **new** function
things.has(onceWrapper.bind({foo: "bar"}));

// This logs true because we're checking for the same function we added
things.has(boundOnceWrapper);
```

Note that even when when calling `bind` with the same `this` argument, it will create a new function **every time**. It doesn't memoize and reuse previous copies.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/add Set.add accepts one argument ?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai - Yeah, I have no idea what `Set` is in the OP's code. I assume it isn't [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) since `Set` doesn't have **`static`** `add` or `has` methods. But `Set` would be a really bizarre identifier to choose regardless of what it is. But the `bind` part of the question was clear enough to answer. :-)